# Data frame with multiple colums, from a group of same values in one column select the maximum in the other column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4 ), B=c(1,2,1,5,10,2,3,1,6,2), B=c(1000,50,400,6,300,2000,20,30,40,50))
```

and I want to filter DF for each group of equal values in A select the Maximum in B.

For example for 0.1 in A the maximum in B is 5.

Ending with the new data frame:

```
A    B    C  
0.1  5    6  
0.2  10   300  
0.3  1    30  
0.4  6    40
```

I am not sure if this a problem to solve with base R or with a library. Because I am thinking to use dplyr and group A. I am correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, using dplyr and grouping by `A`, you can use `slice_max()` (also from dplyr) to select the max value in `B` for each group

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  slice_max(B)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   A [4]
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.1     5     6
2   0.2    10   300
3   0.3     1    30
4   0.4     6    40
```

Comment: ```slice_max(B)``` didn't work 
I had to change to ```slice(which.max(B)```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of base R options:

- Using `subset` + `ave`

```
> subset(DF,as.logical(ave(B,A,FUN = function(x) x == max(x))))
    A  B B.1
4 0.1  5   6
5 0.2 10 300
8 0.3  1  30
9 0.4  6  40
```

- Using `merge` + `aggregate`

```
> merge(aggregate(B~A,DF,max),DF)
    A  B B.1
1 0.1  5   6
2 0.2 10 300
3 0.3  1  30
4 0.4  6  40
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table` where group by 'A', get the index where 'B' is `max` with `which.max`, wrap with `.I` to return the row index.  If we don't specify or rename, by default, it returns as 'V1' column, which we extract as vector to subset the rows of dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[DF[, .I[which.max(B)], A]$V1]
```

-output

```
#     A  B B.1
#1: 0.1  5   6
#2: 0.2 10 300
#3: 0.3  1  30
#4: 0.4  6  40
```